# Exoplayer video zooms in after seeking

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I'm using the exoplayer to play an hls stream. When it loads initially it looks fine, but after calling `seekBack`, `seekForward`, or `seekTo`, the video scaling seems to stop working correctly.

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

XML:

```
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exoPlayer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:resize_mode="fit"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:use_controller="false"/>
```

Initialization:

```
    init {
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
        exoPlayer.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT
        exoPlayer.addListener(this)
    }
```

I'm using exoplayer version 2.18.3

I've tried all the different scaling modes, none seem to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to 2.18.4 resolved this issue

Comment: Interesting that the [release notes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md) don't mention this